# unfortunately application has stopped in android emulator-error ,How to solve this? Below are the logcat messages

Tags: android, eclipse, performance, android-emulator

```
01-19 12:38:42.505: D/AndroidRuntime(14027): Shutting down VM
01-19 12:38:42.505: W/dalvikvm(14027): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c21a68)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.learnactivities/com.example.learnactivities.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at com.example.learnactivities.Main.onCreate(Main.java:17)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4470)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
01-19 12:38:42.525: E/AndroidRuntime(14027):    ... 11 more
01-19 12:38:50.635: I/Process(14027): Sending signal. PID: 14027 SIG: 9
```

Code

```
package com.example.learnactivities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
public class Main extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Main.this, Second.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="188dp"
        android:text="Button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post Main.java and indicate line 17

Comment: package com.example.learnactivities;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
public class Main extends Activity {
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  Button b=(Button) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
  b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Main.this,Second.class ));}
  }); }}

Comment: here `Button b` is `null`. usually id `R.id.action_settings` refers the `MenuItem` id...

Comment: post the xml layout also. likely you referenced wrong id for button

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Main" >

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="188dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
```

You do not have a button with id `action_settings` in `activity_main.xml`

It should be

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

coz you have

```
<Button 
android:id="@+id/button1" // button id is button1
```

Comment: I changed it to Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); and it worked!! Thank you Sir!

Comment: @user3211607 and what happens after changing?

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing wrong id for Button in `findViewById(id)`...

Just replace

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);
```

with

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the error in the line

`Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_settings);`

then you should use `MenuItem`not a `Button` and `OnMenuItemClickListener`